# Windows Shutdown Cancel - restart application that has closed

Tags: winapi, shutdown, application-shutdown

I have an application that stops when the shutdown event is received but this application needs to be continuously running in the user session. If there are programs preventing shutdown and then the user 'cancels' the shutdown the application is no longer running.

Is there a way to have windows restart the application or have the application be the very last application to shut down?

I have read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686227%28VS.85%29.aspx but this only changes the order of the notification, and is not received after the applications preventing a shutdown are terminated.

thanks!

Comment: Which shutdown event are you using?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to have windows restart
>   the application or have the
>   application be the very last
>   application to shut down?

This would violate the "[What if two programs did this?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx)" principal.

Have you used SetProcessShutdownParameters() to delay your apps shut down? Is that not enough?

Answer (score 1):

Add [WM_ENDSESSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to your Windows message handling loop; this is only sent when Windows is in fact shutting down. If for some reason your app needs to intervene in the shutting down process, you can also respond to the [WM_QUERYENDSESSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

Comment: Just a wee clarification: If your app returns TRUE from WM_QUERYENDSESSION then later it will get WM_ENDSESSION even if the session is not ending - wParam will indicate whether it's ending or not.

Comment: @Ciaran; ah yes, that is correct. Didn't catch that and its been a while since I've dealt with this message myself.